CS50P,PS4 Guessing Game: "expected prompt for input, found none"
In CS50P problem set 4's Guessing Game problem, it says prompt the user for range(x) and to get a  number between1 to x, then again prompt user for guess the random number generated by random library  and help him by prompting "Too small!", "Too large!", "Just right!", after each guess.
problem- in terminal going all right and accordingly of instruction of CS50P whenever i try to check50 to check code is written accordingly it giving me this result, also written the cause it says expected prompt for input, found none, i will appreciate even if you give me tip or help me.
check50 output:
:) game.py exists
:) game.py rejects non-numeric level
:) game.py rejects out-of-range level
:) game.py accepts valid level
:) game.py rejects non-numeric guess
:( game.py rejects guess above specified range with "Too large!", expected prompt for input, found none
:( game.py rejects guess above specified range with "Too large!", expected prompt for input, found none
:( game.py outputs "Just right!" when guess is correct, expected prompt for input, found none
:( game.py outputs "Too small!" when guess is too small, expected prompt for input, found none
this is my code:
import random

def game():

    level = asking_for_level()
    random_num = getting_random_number(level)
    answering_the_guess(random_num)

def getting_random_number(level):
    return random.randint(1, level)

def asking_for_level():
    while True:
        try:
           level = int(input("Level: "))
           if level > 0:
              return level
        except ValueError:
               pass

def answering_the_guess(random_num):
    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(input("Guess: "))
            if guess < random_num:
                print("Too small!")
            elif guess > random_num:
                print("Too large!")
            elif guess == random_num:
                print("Just right!")
                break

        except ValueError:
               pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()

a hint or solution how to solve the problem if it can be done

in asking_for_level function try this if level > 1:

As far as I can see, this code should work.  Are you sure this is your real code?

yes i confirm it's real i think some print problem ,thank you for response guyz, and  tried it  if level > 1: seems problem is some way of output problem not the code

problemo is solved , CS50 running it indirectly that's why it getting those errors  and i am using if name ==  "main":
